# Problem with strchr

Tags: c, pointer-arithmetic

I can't get why the following bit of C code doesn't work:

```
int obtainStringLength(char* str, char c1, char c2) {
    char* firstOcurrence = strchr(str, c1);
    char* endOcurrence = strchr(str, c2);
    return 2+(endOcurrence - firstOcurrence) / sizeof(char*);
}
```

The idea is to find how many characters are between `c1` and `c2`:

```
printf("%d\n", obtainStringLength("abc def ghi", 'a', 'i')); //should yield 11
```

Unfortunately, this is always printing 1. What is the problem? Shouldn't `strchr` work like C#'s `string.IndexOf()`?

Comment: You have a very strange compiler :) `always printing 1`????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Division by `sizeof(char*)`? That's incorrect - the result of subtracting two pointers is a numerical value (`ptrdiff_t`) corresponding to the number of values, not a pointer or difference of addresses.

There's also the off-by-one error in calculating the length. So that last line should look like:

```
return 1 + (endOcurrence - firstOcurrence);
```

Comment: Not only that, but each element in the string is `sizeof(char)` bytes, not `sizeof(char*)`.

Comment: True, but not really relevant here - the pointer arithmetic mechanism abstracts away the size of pointed elements here.

Comment: Hmm I thought subtracting a pointer to another would still be a pointer :(

Comment: Nope, that wouldn't make sense. Just like substracting a date from a date isn't a date any more, but a number of, say, days.

Comment: You should also check for `strchr()` returning `NULL`, if either character isn't in the provided string at all.

Answer (score 2):

Your return statement has several problems, due to not understanding pointer arithmetic.

Pointer subtraction already divides by the element size, and `char*` was the wrong type anyway.

And you should be adding 1, not 2.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Because each character occupies exactly `sizeof (char)` bytes; not `sizeof (char*)` bytes.</s>

And `sizeof (char)` is, by definition 1, so you can omit it:

```
return 1 + (endOcurrence - firstOcurrence);
```

Comment: Actually, even if `sizeof(char)` were not 1, the division would be wrong. That's because pointer subtraction yields array index or number of elements, not number of bytes between the two pointers.

Answer (score 0):

No, strchr() returns a pointer (the address of) the character being sought, or NULL if the character was not found.

That's very different from IndexOf().

Comment: The OP seems to already know that, judging from the code presented.

Comment: I didn't see where he handles NULL. Also, he specifically asked about IndexOf().